# Java Android ping IOException "Too many files open" when starting a process

Tags: java, android, multithreading, process, ping

I'm creating an Android app that pings many hosts on the network...

To do this I'm using the ping command at /system/bin/ping. Apparently this gives me an IOException "Too many files open". I presume this is because I'm not closing something properly and am bogging up the resources with it. I tried closing the inputstream but that didn't help.

This happens when I start using pingHost() many times constantly... I have a button that you press to start and cancel a scan for the network. Each ping is run on a separate thread and will stop when the button is pressed to stop them setting a boolean "runnable" variable to false. If this button is pressed on and off a few times, it becomes slower. That's not cool. lol

I've been fooling around with the program to try and figure out what I'm forgetting to close, but have been unsuccessful.

I've tried proc.destroy() but it fails to destroy the process. I'm assuming this would also raise a problem with returning the exitValue() of proc. There is probably a simple solution I'm not understanding. I've been fooling around with this for a while with no luck. I would like some help if possible! :)

```
public static int pingHost(String host) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String cmd = "/system/bin/ping -c 1 -W 1000 " + host;
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    proc.waitFor();

    input.close();
    return proc.exitValue();
}
```

> Blockquote at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
>   12-31 16:24:07.306 13243-15816/sage.networktools W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:168)
>   12-31 16:24:07.306 13243-15816/sage.networktools W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:241)
>   12-31 16:24:07.306 13243-15816/sage.networktools W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:184)
>   12-31 16:24:07.306 13243-15816/sage.networktools W/System.err:     at sage.networktools.MainActivity.**pingHost(MainActivity.java:98)**
>   12-31 16:24:07.316 13243-15791/sage.networktools W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:184)
>   12-31 16:24:07.316 13243-15791/sage.networktools W/System.err:     at sage.networktools.MainActivity.pingHost(MainActivity.java:98)
>   12-31 16:24:07.316 13243-15791/sage.networktools W/System.err:     at sage.networktools.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:189)
>   12-31 16:24:07.316 13243-15791/sage.networktools W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>   12-31 16:24:07.316 13243-15791/sage.networktools W/System.err: Caused by: **java.io.IOException: Too many open files**
>   12-31 16:24:07.316 13243-15791/sage.networktools W/System.err:     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
>   12-31 16:24:07.316 13243-15791/sage.networktools W/System.err:     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)

Comment: I'm thinking it's more of a problem with having too many processes running since each thread makes a new process. Maybe there is a way to stop all the processes when the stop button is pressed? They should already be stopped when you get the exitValue... not sure :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like in your case process is not getting destroyed ,  You can try using `process.destroy()` after `process.waitFor()`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a very annoying fix for my problem. If there is a cleaner solution please let me know.

I added every thread that is created to an ArrayList. When the stop button is clicked, I interrupt every thread in the list.

Still not the kind of solution I was hoping for... but at least it works.